# Debian 8 jessie: The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck

Tags: debian, initramfs, bios

I was working in Atom on a small webpage and suddendly it would not let me save my file, saying that read-only mode was turned on. I tried to update in the terminal but that would not let me either, so I rebooted hoping that would fix the issue.  Instead I ran into more problems.

The first error was in the BIOS: `HP error 501`.
I pressed enter to continue and this screen popped up:

```
Loading, please wait...
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda1:
Deleted inode 1048599 has zero dtime.  FIXED.
/dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY:; RUN fsck MANUALLY
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck
modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in modules.dep


BusyBox v1.22.1 (Debian 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
(initramfs) _
```

Now I am stuck on the `(initramfs)` command prompt.

How can I get back to my system and files?

Comment: `HP Error 501` appears to describe a corrupt or missing EFI system partition.  Is this a new error?  Have you been able to boot Linux without seeing this error before?  If so, and judging from the output of `fsck`, you might have a failing hard drive.  A quick search of `HP Error 501` seems to note that disabling `HP Quicklook` in the BIOS tends to fix that error though, so that may not be the case

Comment: @Fox Yes this is the first time that this error popped up. So how would I reboot again to get into BIOS. Because I am stuck on the initramfs command and typing in reboot does nothing

Comment: The `(initramfs)` prompt is an actual shell prompt.  If `reboot` the command doesn't work, you might try `init 6`.  Failing that, Alt+SysRq+REISUB is a key sequence to reboot in Linux, which might work here

Comment: @Fox so init 6 came up with "must be run as PID 1." Do you think I should just put in the bootable DVD?

Comment: As a last attempt before that, you might try `telinit 6`, which is what `init 6` would actually call.  Though at this point, it doesn't seem that anything is mounted, and holding the power button is probably as reasonable as anything

Comment: @Fox do you think this problem is because Debian is uncompatible with my machine? Or maybe my hard drive is actually failing?

Comment: It isn't necessarily either, though keeping regular backups never hurts.  Drive corruption can be software bugs, failing hardware, bad cabling, or a myriad of other things.  And this may not even _be_ drive corruption.  Do you have a second machine you can put it in (that is, with different cabling) to check?  Anecdote: my CD drive would close immediately upon being opened until I replaced the SATA data cable, so cabling can do unexpected things.

Comment: @Fox yes tomorrow I am picking up a Windows laptop to use for homework and have this linux machine solely for studying unix

Comment: In the (initramfs) prompt, the regular `init` (whether SysVinit or `systemd`) might not be running, which would explain why a regular `reboot` command won't work. Instead, you can use the old-school `sync; sync; sync; reboot -f`. In other words: manually make sure all the write operations are completed, and then send the kernel the command to immediately reboot the system instead of signaling the init system to perform a shutdown. If the root filesystem is needing a filesystem check, it is probably in read-only mode anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Write `fsck /dev/sdax` (depends on the drive infected "sda1,sda2 etc") And then enter Then it will ask you many questions for editing just type Yes and after that restart it.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It looks quite correct for me. (The option -y does the same as typing Yes for every question, which I would not recommend.)